# Is there an R function or string of code to identify when two cells columns in a row are duplicates?

Tags: r, spatial

I have a dataframe in R with roughly 1,700 observations. I intersected GPS points with polygons, and want to determine if multiple IDs enter in the same polygon in the same 12 hour period (6pm to 6 am). Here is the head of my dataframe.

```
  ID           date              time     DOP       datetime        p   pid1  Long     Lat
 289 Friday, September 1, 2017 1:15:29 AM 4.2 2017-09-01 01:15:29 <NA>    2 763692.8 3617676
 289 Friday, September 1, 2017 4:15:15 AM 1.4 2017-09-01 04:15:15 <NA>    2 763674.5 3617692
 299 Friday, September 1, 2017 5:00:16 AM 3.6 2017-09-01 05:00:16 <NA>    2 764427.2 3616750
  13 Friday, September 1, 2017 5:15:25 AM 2.8 2017-09-01 05:15:25 <NA>    1 767800.5 3613057
 299 Friday, September 1, 2017 5:15:29 AM 1.6 2017-09-01 05:15:29 <NA>    2 764420.7 3616746
 299 Friday, September 1, 2017 5:30:08 AM 1.4 2017-09-01 05:30:08 <NA>    2 764420.7 3616747
```

You can see that for Friday September 1st, 2017, both ID numbers 289 and 299 where within PID1 #2 (PID1 #2 refers to polygon #2) at one point (roughly 45 minutes apart). I'd like to have some function or script to run through my dataset and identify instances where this occurs. That way I can identify what IDs are in what PID1 during specific times (within the 12 hour window), to ultimately have a dataset that shows how many times multiple IDs interact within a specific polygon.

Here is a sample dataset using dput for the first 5 lines of my dataset:

```
structure(list(X = c("388933", "387022", "507722", "941954", 
"506441"), ID = structure(c(12L, 12L, 15L, 1L, 15L), .Label = c("13", 
"17", "97", "100", "253", "255", "256", "259", "263", "272", 
"281", "289", "294", "297", "299", "329", "337", "339", "344", 
"347"), class = "factor"), date = c("Friday, September 1, 2017", 
"Friday, September 1, 2017", "Friday, September 1, 2017", "Friday, September 1, 2017", 
"Friday, September 1, 2017"), time = c("1:15:29 AM", "4:15:15 AM", 
"5:00:16 AM", "5:15:25 AM", "5:15:29 AM"), DOP = c(4.2, 1.4, 
3.6, 2.8, 1.6), datetime = structure(c(1504246529, 1504257315, 
1504260016, 1504260925, 1504260929), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "CST6CDT"), p = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), pid1 = c("2", "2", "2", "1", "2"
), Long = c(763692.811797531, 763674.546077539, 764427.163679506, 
767800.455784065, 764420.684442097), Lat = c(3617675.85664874, 
3617692.02070415, 3616749.72487458, 3613057.33334349, 3616746.22303673
)), row.names = c("224811", "223697", "277383", "525686", "276768"
), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: I am editing this to show the way that I figured out to make this work.

```
uni <- unique(df[,c("ID","date", "pid1")])
df2 <- aggregate(ID~pid1+date, data= uni,length)
```

This was able to create a dataframe with the number of unique IDs per pid1 per day.

Thank you

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @ChuckP, I'm not entirely sure how it would/could look. I would like to be able to produce some type of dataframe or even column within the dataframe that would let me see how many IDs intersected pid1 #2 on 2017-09-01 and so forth.

Comment: @RonakShah I'm not sure of the expected output, that's part of my issue, but I did use dput to give some data.

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df[c("ID","date", "pid1")]),]`

Answer (score 0):

**Major EDIT**

Give it a try now on your real data.  I think I was letting the fact that ID was a factor get in the way.  If we agree thos is giving you the right ideas we can close the basics out and perhaps start a new question on your 12 hour blocks.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(2020)
ID <- sample(10:200, replace = TRUE, size = 1000)
PID <- sample(1:31, replace = TRUE, size = 1000)
Date <- sample(c("Friday, September 1, 2017",
                  "Saturday, September 2, 2017",
                  "Sunday, September 3, 2017",
                  "Monday, September 4, 2017",
                  "Tuesday, September 5, 2017",
                  "Wednesday, September 6, 2017",
                  "Thursday, September 7, 2017",
                  "Friday, September 8, 2017"),
                replace = TRUE,
                size = 1000)

play <- data.frame(ID, Date, PID)
play$ID <- factor(play$ID)


ids_by_pid <- 
  play %>%
  mutate(ID = as.integer(as.character(ID))) %>%
  arrange(Date, PID, ID) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = Date,
                     values_from = ID,
                     names_from = PID,
                     names_prefix = "pid",
                     names_sort = TRUE,
                     values_fn = list)
```

Here's the code I use to compare IDs in a PID for a particular day

```r
play %>% 
  filter(Date == "Saturday, September 2, 2017", PID == "1") %>%
  pull(ID) 
#> [1] 40  30  89  133 36 
#> 189 Levels: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 ... 200


ids_by_pid %>% 
  filter(Date == "Saturday, September 2, 2017") %>% 
  select(pid1) %>% 
  pull %>%
  unlist
#> [1]  30  36  40  89 133
```

Comment: So I think this may be close to what I was wanting. With this example, it gives three columns. The first column is the date. What do the other two columns refer too?

Comment: The columns will always be unique values of `pid1`.  The entries in the columns will always be unique `ID`s who were in that column.  So `results$pid1` contains just an entry for 13 the only ID that entered and `results$pid2` contains 288 & 289 who were both there.

Comment: And each row in column one is a different date. So it'll show the IDs which were in each unique pid1 for each date? I'm not sure that is working as intended, I ran it on a full dataset that is 6 months long and it's only identifying 34 days that an ID was within a specific PID and I know that's not correct.

Comment: Can you share the data for the date you know is wrong?  How many different pid1's are there by the way?

Comment: its to long to share it all. In the full dataset there are 31 different pid1s for 6 months (Sep 1 - Feb 28th) of data with 20 different IDs. Your fake dataset you made works well as a substitute, but its not accurately identifying the unique IDs that were within each PID1 on each day. What is the "ids_by_pid$pid1" line of code showing?

Comment: For example, it will show me ID 13 was within pid1 #19 on September 1st, but it won't show me that ID 289 was within PID1 #31 on September 1st.